# Heatmap or contour plot using polar coordinates in Julia

Tags: matplotlib, plot, jupyter-notebook, julia, polar-coordinates

How can one plot contours or colours using Julia plotting tools (including PyPlot)?

Functions with variability along the radius plot fine but once I introduce variability along the circumference the plots are strange. Is it a bug or do I do sth wrong?

#### 1) Function with variability along the radial direction is OK:

```
r = range(0,length=11, stop=1);
θ = range(0,length=51, stop=2*pi);
f(r,θ) = r^2;
values = f.(r,θ');

using Plots
pyplot()
hm = heatmap(values, proj=:polar, legend=true)
```

[image: radialFunction]

#### 2) Function with variability along the circumference results is a strange plot :(

```
f(r,θ) = r^2 * sin(θ * pi/180);
values = f.(r,θ');
```

The cross-section around the circumference has variability as shown below:

[image: circumeferentialCrossSection]

Unfortunately, the heatmap produces this:

```
using Plots
pyplot()
hm = heatmap(values, proj=:polar, legend=true)
```

[image: functionOfTheta]

What is happening? Why is the plot not as expected?

PS
Interestingly, even though I use a scale from 0 .. 2Pi, the plots display 0-360 deg. I have tried to use theta = 0 .. 360 deg but the plot remains the same.

Comment: The angle needs to be in radiants (i.e. a circle goes from 0 to 2pi). When you have data from 0 to 360 it will wind around the plot 60 times.